# How to improve chart generated from D3noob's tutorial using ds.js

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, d3.js, charts

I have been able to create a chart using D3noob's tutorial (http://www.d3noob.org/2013/02/using-mysql-database-as-source-of-data.html) but chart generated is not as it is in the tutorial.

Below are the graphical representation of both the sample and the one I generated.

I am now going to add all the source codes (data2.php and simple-graph.html), which are used below:

data2.php

```
<?php
    $username = "homedbuser"; 
    $password = "homedb";   
    $host = "localhost";
    $database="homedb";

    $server = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
    $connection = mysql_select_db($database, $server);

    $myquery = "SELECT  `date`, `close` FROM  `data2`";
    $query = mysql_query($myquery);

    if ( ! $query ) {
        echo mysql_error();
        die;
    }

    $data = array();

    for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query); $x++) {
        $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    }

    echo json_encode($data);     

    mysql_close($server);
?>
```

simple-graph.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<style>

</style>
<body>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50}, //{top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right, //width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 470 - margin.top - margin.bottom; //height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
d3.json("data2.php", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.close = +d.close;
    });
    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

    svg.append("path")      // Add the valueline path.
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline(data));

    svg.append("g")         // Add the X Axis
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")         // Add the Y Axis
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

});
    </script>

</body>
```

Problem: All I want to do is generate graph similar to the one in the tutorial. I'm able to generate a graph but instead of showing April April 08 April 15 April 22 April 29 (as shown in http://www.d3noob.org/2013/02/using-mysql-database-as-source-of-data.html) along the x-axis, it's showing April July October 2013 April and that made the graph looked different.

Thanks.
Ruth.

Comment: It looks to me like the tutorial's code (actually, the data file provided in the download, though I haven't downloaded it) just doesn't match up with the example image provided at the bottom of the tutorial. If you change the values you have in your MySQL database it should change the range of the X axis in the graph because it appears the X axis range is picked from those values. I would recommend combining jquery and highcharts for something like this though but that's not very helpful for you to get *this* working.

Comment: I have made some changes to the data, below is the data and the graph. http://teesams.com/graph.bmp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting a date range along the bottom of your graph showing showing April July October 2013 April it would indicate that the data in your database has a much larger date range than the sample data in the tutorial.

d3.js is extremely clever in adjusting the axis values to suit the data, so if you are seeing a range from April (I presume 2012) to April 2013, it would indicate that your data extends over that range. (the data in the example is for the range 27 March 2012 to 1 May 2012).

Check your data and see if there is a typo in there.

**Edit: 2014-08-15**

The other problem that you're encountering with the graph looking strange and blocky is because the `<style>` information isn't in your html code.

If you check out the simple-graph.html code (from the provided download or there's a live example here http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/b3ff6ae1c120eea654b5) you should see the following section at the start;

```
<style> /* set the CSS */

body { font: 12px Arial;}

path { 
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

</style>
```

Add this in and it should improve. Have a read of the book (https://leanpub.com/D3-Tips-and-Tricks) especially the CSS section right at the start and it will explain what you're seeing (in fact some of the examples of when CSS goes nasty are remarkably like yours!)

Comment: I have edited the data, the result seem better but still some issues. Take a look at the data and the graph presented. http://teesams.com/graph.bmp

Comment: Below is the previous data and graph. http://teesams.com/oldgraph.bmp I just want a line graph as presented in the tutorial.

Comment: Ahh... The date range now looks good. The last issue is with including the css in the `style` section. I have edited the answer above to give some direction to sort out the styling.

Comment: Thanks the problem was the style and its now resolved. Thanks.